# Get last 4 digits of credit card after successful Stripe subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe.js

For compliance reasons I am generating tokens on the client side and sending those details to stripe. I want to display the **last four digits and the type of card** on my confirmation page

I am creating a customer

```
// Create a Customer:
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([

  'source' => $token,

  'email' =>  $current_user->user_email,

]);
```

than adding them to a subscription

```
//create the subscription for the customer
  $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(

        'customer' => $customer->id,

        "items" => array(
                      array(
                         "plan" => "dpc-standard",
                      ),
         )
    ));
```

The subscription returns https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object
a ton of data including the invoice_id that is generated for the subscription but doesn't return any CC details

Comment: Well if it doesn't return any CC details you simply can't get the details...

Comment: @MehdiBounya you can make additional calls to the to get the invoice, from the invoice get the charge from the charge get the credit card details but that adds 3 additional calls to my checkout process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Customer and pass the `source` parameter set to a token id, it will save that card on the new customer. The value returned by this call is a Customer [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) with the `sources` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-sources) which will contain the new card you just saved.

You can access the last 4 digits easily using:

```
$last4 = $customer->sources->data[0]->last4;
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Thank you, I really appreciate it. I had just finished writing a get wrapper that would match dates on charges and subscription to get me the card. This is much bettter